# Writing a PHP code in a variable to a file

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to put a php code into a php variable and then write it to a file. But it does not work. Since it contains tabs, ][? space, new line etc. 
I tried to use EOD did not work.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);  
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$content02 = "\n";
$content01 = <<<EOD
<?php session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["UserData"]["Username"])){
   header("location:login.php");
   exit;
   }
?>
EOD;
$content03='<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Spambox</title></head><body><html dir="rtl"></html><form action="flushsink.php" method="get"><input type="submit" value="Flush!"></form>';
$content4 = $content01.$content02.$content03;
function writeUTF8File($filename,$content) {
    $f=fopen($filename,"w");
    fwrite($f,$content);
    fclose($f);
}
writeUTF8File("spams.php",$content4);
header('Location: http://targeturl.com/int/spams.php');
?>
```

So basically I am flushing a spams.php file with new php code. But I can not write the php code to the file properly.

If I change the line 5 to :

```
$content01 = '<?php session_start(); if(!isset($_SESSION["UserData"]["Username"])){ header("location:login.php");   exit;}?>';
```

The application will write to the spams.php but the redirection (header()) does not work any more.

Any idea to put multiple line values containing php code to a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create an array of strings, so you can simply [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array. This way you can achive a better formatted code. I just did this for example with your PHP, you can also do this with your HTML.

By the way, I changed the path of your `header("Location: ....spams.php");` for my test, just change it back and try the code below:

```
$content = array();
$content[] = '<?php';
$content[] = 'session_start();';
$content[] = 'if( !isset( $_SESSION["UserData"]["Username"] ) ) {';
$content[] = '  header("Location: login.php");';
$content[] = '  exit;';
$content[] = '}';
$content[] = '?>';
// for better readability you can also split the html below, like I did with the PHP above
$content[] = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>IrNut Spambox</title></head><body><html dir="rtl"></html><form action="flushsink.php" method="get"><input type="submit" value="Flush!"></form>';

// implode array to string, glue will be a \n
$content = implode( "\n", $content );

function writeUTF8File($filename,$content) {
    $f=fopen($filename,"w");
    fwrite($f,$content);
    fclose($f);
}
writeUTF8File( "spams.php", $content) ;
header('Location: spams.php');// just changed the path to fit my test
```

The **spams.php** will look like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if( !isset( $_SESSION["UserData"]["Username"] ) ) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>IrNut Spa.......
```

Comment: Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
$content01 =
    "<?php \n" .
    "session_start(); \n" .
    "if (!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])) \n" .
    "{ \n" .
    "header('location:login.php'); \n" .
    "exit; \n" .
    "}?> \n"
    ;
```

Comment: Nope. PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in your code on line 8
"if (!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])) \n" .
PHP Syntax Check: Errors parsing your code

Comment: If you re-type the apostrophes, does it work?  (Copying-and-pasting the apostrophes may be an issue.)